# How does the step up booster in the attached schematic work?

Tags: integrated-circuit, step-up

There is a 3 pin SOT-89 package IC DC step up that converts 1.5 V to 3.3 V as shown in the picture.

My questions are:

1. Does anybody have a link to the datasheet of the 433p?
2. How does this circuit work?

[image]

Comment: Is the device marked 433p on top? Please provide a photo of it.

Comment: An inductor across the output O_o

Comment: https://postimg.cc/0KY8YNWy

Answer (score 1):

> *How this circuit works?*

It doesn't work; it's incorrectly drawn or transcribed. You can't have an inductor with 3.3 volts on one terminal and 0 volts on the other terminal because it will short out the 3.3 volts. Somewhere you have made a mistake.

Comment: It is strange  GND connected to output .Normally inductor is in serie with input but as you can see in the picture attached link there is a component right of diode that is short circuit with ohm check and i think it is inductor , may be it is capacitor but why it is short circuit , bythe way the picture is attached  https://postimg.cc/0KY8YNWy

Comment: @Ali It looks more like a capacitor to me and anyway, in-circuit measurements of components is not a reliable way to measure.

Comment: @Ali if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.